# How to write content to a new page when it exceeds the given rectangle area (itext7)

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

How can I get the current page number?

Use case: An apllication written using itext5 needs to be rewritten using itext7.
Our app generates PDF files for our customer's monthly bills.

Structure of the pdf:

1. Create document:

   ```
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename));
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4);
    document.setMargins(82, 35, 0, 38);
    buildBody(pdfData, document, writer);
    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new PdfStartPageHandler<>(pdfData, document, this));
    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new PdfEndPageHandler(document));
    buildBodyContent(pdfData, document, writer);
    document.close();
   ```

2.Each IEventHandler instance has this format(except the rectangle values):

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
  document.add(lineSeparatorHeader);
  document.add(paragraphInfo); // 
  document.add(lineSeparatorHeader);
}
```

paragraphInfo - is a Paragraph() which consists of one table with two columns

lineSeparatorHeader - is a LineSeparator()

3. The **buildBody(pdfData, document, writer)** must fill the body of my pdf page.

**My problem** is that I don't know how to handle the situation when the content exceeds the size of the rectangle. I would like it to create a new page, generate a new rectangle with the same dimensions and continue writing there.
[image]

A. is the header which needs to be on every page
B. is the body whose content is may occupy more than one page. In case it occupies more than one page, the new page must also contain the header and the footer.
C. is the footer

Comment: Hi, you can just use proper margins and add content directly to the `Document` instance - why do you need to manually manage the rectangle and elements inside of it? Can you attach your minimal reproducible code sample and describe what is the difference between the current behavior and the desired behavior?

Comment: The problem is that without defining rectangles for every part of the page (header, body and footer) the header content overlaps with the body content. I do not understand why since I do not make any changes to the document (Such as changing Renderers).

Comment: Now I am trying to define canvases for the EventHandlers, but the canvas content seems to be overlapped by the document content. (I know it is overlapped since I can find the content in the page using the search option of a pdf). I found that I must use "new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(),page.getResources(), pdfDoc)" instead of  "PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(),page.getResources(), pdfDoc)" but this still does not work.

Comment: Let's talk code and sketches of desired behavior :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accumulating your ideas and some suggestions from the comments, the following could be done:

1. Reserve space for a footer and a header by setting margins on a `Document` instance, ensuring that no content added to the `Document` will be placed on them.
2. Add footer and header events as you've already done.

   ```
   PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
   Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

   int headerHeight = 100;
   int footerHeight = 200;

   float[] oldMargins = new float[] {doc.getTopMargin(), doc.getRightMargin(), doc.getBottomMargin(),
           doc.getLeftMargin()};
   doc.setMargins(doc.getTopMargin() + headerHeight, doc.getRightMargin(), doc.getBottomMargin() + footerHeight,
           doc.getLeftMargin());

   pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new IEventHandler() {
       @Override
       public void handleEvent(Event event) {
           PdfDocumentEvent pdfDocumentEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
           PdfPage page = pdfDocumentEvent.getPage();
           Rectangle pageRectangle = page.getPageSize();
           Rectangle headerArea = new Rectangle(oldMargins[3], pageRectangle.getTop() - oldMargins[0] - headerHeight,
                   pageRectangle.getWidth() - oldMargins[1] - oldMargins[3], headerHeight);
           new Canvas(page, headerArea).add(
                   new Div()
                           .setHeight(headerArea.getHeight())
                           .setWidth(headerArea.getWidth())
                           .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.RED))
                   .close();
       }
   });
   pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new IEventHandler(){
       @Override
       public void handleEvent(Event event) {
           PdfDocumentEvent pdfDocumentEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
           PdfPage page = pdfDocumentEvent.getPage();
           Rectangle pageRectangle = page.getPageSize();
           Rectangle footerArea = new Rectangle(oldMargins[3], pageRectangle.getBottom() + oldMargins[2],
                   pageRectangle.getWidth() - oldMargins[1] - oldMargins[3], footerHeight);
           new Canvas(page, footerArea).add(
                   new Div()
                           .setHeight(footerArea.getHeight())
                           .setWidth(footerArea.getWidth())
                           .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.YELLOW))
                   .close();
       }
   });

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       doc.add(new Paragraph("I'm body's paragraph #" + i));
   }

   doc.close();
   ```

The resultant PDF looks as expected (no content overflows the footers and the headers):
[image]